# i got native Exception on sqlCE - working with Windows-CE

Tags: c#, windows-ce, sql-server-ce

I get Native Exception from sqlCE on Windows-CE and when I try to catch the error with `try` and `catch` I still get the error. When I install sqlCE again, it works fine.

How do I properly catch this exception and how do I fix it?

Comment: We need more info on what causes it.  You say "reinstalling" fixes it.  Does that installation get corrupted and fail while running, or does the error only happen after some event like a device reset?

Answer (score 0):

If the root file system of the operating system on your device is configured as non-persistent, but the Windows registry is persistent, then every time you restart the device your dlls for SQLCE will get deleted. However since the registry is persistent, windows ce will still report SQLCE as installed, but you will get exceptions if you try to use it.